# hybris Flexiblesearch - where clause with enums

Tags: enums, sap-commerce-cloud

I successfully create and execute a flexiblesearch query with a WHERE clause comparing a custom property, added to CartModel, with a enum value. 
But I don't know how to "translate" it to try on HAC (just to try and fix it before coding inside a class).
In my class I've the working code:

```
String MY_QUERY = "SELECT {" + CartModel.PK + "} FROM {" + CartModel._TYPECODE + "} "
                        + "WHERE " + "( {" + CartModel.RESERVATIONORDERSTATUS + "} = ?reservedOnHybris)";
```

And I set the **reservedOnHybris** parameter with

```
  searchQuery.addQueryParameter("reservedOnHybris", ReservationOrderStatus.INITIAL_STATUS);
```

How can I translate this to try it on the FlexibleSearch panel in the HAC?
Thanks in advance.

Ale

Comment: You can check the PK of your EnumValue in HMC and replace it with reservedOnHybris parameter. `select {PK} from {Cart} where {RESERVATIONORDERSTATUS} = ENUM_VALUE_PK`

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
String MY_QUERY = "SELECT {" + CartModel.PK + "} FROM {" + CartModel._TYPECODE + "} "
                    + "WHERE " + "( {" + CartModel.RESERVATIONORDERSTATUS + "} = 
                    ({{SELECT {crse.PK} FROM {" + CartReservationStatusEnum._TYPECODE 
                    + " as crse} WHERE {crse.code} = '" + ?reservedOnHybris + "'}}))"
```

You should get the PK of your enum, you could do this by using a select query.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT {PK} FROM {Cart} WHERE {RESERVATIONORDERSTATUS} = "Your status"
```

Basically things like "CartModel.PK" could be replaced by the String.